# Add one Marker to Multiple FeatureGroups in Folium Python

Tags: python, leaflet, google-maps-markers, folium

I'm trying to make a map in python using Folium to show the location of some facilities. Each facility might have several features which I want to use to filter the markers. As far as I know it's possible using [FeatureGroup](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html).
But what I need is adding one single marker to multiple FeatureGroups, as each marker could have several features.

Here is what I tried so far:

```py
# making a FeatureGroup for each feature

feature_group = {}
for feature in features_set:
  feature_group[str(feature)] = folium.FeatureGroup(name=feature, show=False)
```

```
# making a marker for each facility 

for facility in facilities:
  # say I store all features of this facility in 'feature' variable
  for f in features_set:
    if f in features:
      marker = folium.Marker(location=[lan, lon]).add_to(feature_group[f])
```

At the end I add all FeatureGroups and a LayerControl to my map.

```
for f in feature_group:
  map.add_child(feature_group[f])

folium.LayerControl().add_to(map)
```

This solution works because I am making a new marker when I want to add it to the FeatureGroup. But is there a better way to do this? Cause right now there are multiple markers for each spot on the map to get the FeatureGroups working.

[image: map using folium FeatureGroup in python]